# Using ROS with Velodyne HDL-32E

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon.

I would like to know: is the code published in here, concerning the use and installation of ROS for Velodyne HDL-64E, on Linux OS, applicable to the 32E version of the sensor?

I understand the functions might not work with the 32E Velodyne, but I am more interested on data acquisition. Can I get data from the 32E version of Velodyne, using ROS available for the 64E version?

If yes, how can I do it? I mean, what am I supposed to do right after I install ROS on Linux Ubuntu Diamondback for checking if ROS is installed correctly and how can I get the data package from the sensor?

Thank you!

Victor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12086/using-ros-with-velodyne-hdl-32e/) by [Victor Lourenção](https://answers.ros.org/users/1441/victor-louren%C3%A7%C3%A3o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Velodyne HDL-32E is not currently supported.

I maintain that driver, but do not have an HDL-32E available for testing. I will gladly assist anyone able to provide a patch adding support for that device.

Someone already supplied a patch for the HDL-64E S2, which is why we can now support that model.

UPDATE: I am now working on adding 32E support in the new [`velodyne_driver`](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_driver) implementation. Interested users have supplied PCAP dumps from that device and volunteered to run tests.

UPDATE2: Thanks to the assistance of @Ryan and others, the HDL-32E is now fully supported by the ROS `velodyne` stack.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2